# Using preventDefault

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax, standards, preventdefault

I've been looking at some code posted by someone and I can't make sense of why he used preventDefault.

```
var $windows = $('#tgx-window,#tgs-window,#tgm-window,#tgl-window'), $buttons = $('#tgx-button,#tgs-button,#tgm-button,#tgl-button');
$windows.hide();

$buttons.on('click', function(e) {
    var $id;
    e.preventDefault();
    $buttons.removeClass('closebutton');
    $id = $('#' + this.id.split('-')[0] + '-window');// Get window id
    $windows.slideUp();
    if(! $id.is(':visible') ) {
        $id.slideDown();
        $(this).addClass('closebutton');
    }
});
```

It seems to behave exactly the same with or without it. My best guess so far is that it's common practice to use preventDefault/return false in function bodies.

**My question is why he used that method at all?**

Oh, yeah. I'm new to JavaScript.

http://jsfiddle.net/62NPt/53/

Comment: I guess it's only useful when the button is type of submit.

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/TPB6K/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the **[docs:](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)**

> If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be
>   triggered.

So if your button is an input submit button for example, the `event.preventDefault()` will prevent the default behaviour of your button and prevent your form from submitting and reload the page. This is normally helpful when you want to apply **[AJAX](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)** call.

Comment: So would you say that its use in the script is useless?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. It's being used here as a variable to select four elements. It's a really clever script, which is why I'm trying to understand it completely. I have similar code, and mine is infinitely longer and more verbose and repetitive.

Comment: Sorry, just ignore my last comment. The answer is yes. Based on your HTML markup, `$buttons` is just a normal `<button>` and its task is to slide up and slide down a hidden content so `e.preventDefault()` is completely useless in this case.

Comment: Felix, my question was *why* he used it, not what it does. That wasn't answered here... should I edit my post to include that, "preventDefault was used by "accident"?

Comment: I think I've already mention the answer which is yes, in your case `e.preventDefault()` is completely redundant here.

Comment: I see. It was answered in the comments. Gotcha. I'll fix it.

Comment: @Sophisticake I doubt `preventDefault()` was used by accident. Without seeing the context of **how** this script was used, the only assumption one can make is that the author wanted the script to behave the same regardless of what the triggering element(s) were. Preventing the default action stops accidental form submissions and page scrolling (from hyperlinks with, say, just `href="#"` or similar).

Comment: The context of the script is linked above. You'll notice there is no use for it anywhere. http://jsfiddle.net/62NPt/5/ correct?

Answer (score 3):

If the button is of type `submit` and in case of `anchor` if you use `preventDefault()` the default action of the event will not be triggered.

If you dont want to stop default action of element then it does not make any difference.

Comment: Which is why I was confused by its presence.

Comment: @Sophisticake: No Issues Bro. You can use if you want to stop default action. Otherwise I will suggest you to not use preventDefault(). Hope this helps you :)

Comment: Thanks. I guess whomever wrote that script was very used to the practice of adding it and didn't see the point in removing it. Thanks for the help.